# Make large allocations be automatically committed on first touch

Tags: winapi, unmanaged

How can I allocate memory in Windows but not have it committed until first touch?

I see that `VirtualAlloc` lets me reserve a range of memory, but I then need to manually commit sections of that memory before use.  I'd like the committing to be automatic when I first reference it.

Also, if possible, I do not want the memory zeroed before being committed.

(As an aside, this can be done on Linux by setting up a private memory mapping of a chunk of /dev/zero)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a smart-pointer of your own design which commits it upon first dereference (by of course overloading the dereference & indirection operators).

This is an example smart pointer which creates an instance of a given object upon first dereference (lazy instantiation).  Same idea, basically:

```
template <typename T>
struct default_constructor_factory
{
    T * operator ()() { return new T; }
};

template <typename T, typename F = default_constructor_factory<T> >
class lazy_ptr : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef F factory_type;
    typedef lazy_ptr<T,F> this_type;

    lazy_ptr() : m_ptr(), m_factory() { }
    lazy_ptr(F factory) : m_ptr(), m_factory(factory) { }
    ~lazy_ptr() { if (m_ptr != NULL) delete m_ptr; }

    T & operator* () const
    {
        return *get();
    }

    T * operator-> () const
    {
        return get();
    }

    T * get() const
    {
        if (m_ptr == NULL)
            m_ptr = m_factory();
        return m_ptr;
    }

    void reset(T * p)
    {
        if (p != m_ptr)
        {
            if (m_ptr != NULL)
                delete m_ptr;
            m_ptr = p;
        }
    }

    T * release()
    {
        T * p = m_ptr;
        m_ptr = NULL;
        return p;
    }

    // non-dereferencing accessors

    T * peek() const
    {
        // may return NULL
        return m_ptr;
    }

    bool dereferenced() const
    {
        return peek() != NULL;
    }

//  operator bool() const { return dereferenced(); }

    // handle intrinsic conversion to testable bool using unspecified_bool technique
    typedef T * this_type::*unspecified_bool_type;
    operator unspecified_bool_type() const // never throws
    {
        return dereferenced() ? &this_type::m_ptr : NULL;
    }

private:
    // we must remain it's only owner!
    mutable T * m_ptr;

    // our factory generates the needed element on-demand
    mutable factory_type m_factory;
};

// shared_lazy_ptr
//
// we act as a copyable lazy pointer
// essentially, we add reference counting to a single shared lazy pointer
//
template <typename T, typename F = default_constructor_factory<T> >
class shared_lazy_ptr
{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef F factory_type;
    typedef lazy_ptr<T,F> ptr_type;
    typedef shared_lazy_ptr<T,F> this_type;

    shared_lazy_ptr() : m_ptr(new ptr_type) { }
    shared_lazy_ptr(F factory) : m_ptr(new ptr_type(factory)) { }

    // copy ctor
    shared_lazy_ptr(const this_type & rhs) : m_ptr(rhs.m_ptr), m_references(rhs.m_references) { }

    // assignment
    this_type & operator = (const this_type & rhs)
    {
        if (m_references.Reattach(rhs.m_references))
            delete m_ptr;
        m_ptr = rhs.m_ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~shared_lazy_ptr() 
    {
        if (m_references.IsOnly())
            delete m_ptr;
    }

    T & operator* () const
    {
        return *get();
    }

    T * operator-> () const
    {
        return get();
    }

    T * get() const
    {
        return m_ptr->get();
    }

    void reset(T * p)
    {
        if (p != get())
        {
            if (m_ptr != NULL)
                delete m_ptr;
            m_ptr = p;
        }
    }

    // non-dereferencing accessors

    T * peek() const
    {
        // may return NULL
        return get()->peek();
    }

    bool dereferenced() const
    {
        return peek() != NULL;
    }

//  operator bool() const { return dereferenced(); }

    // handle intrinsic conversion to testable bool using unspecified_bool technique
    typedef T * this_type::*unspecified_bool_type;
    operator unspecified_bool_type() const // never throws
    {
        return dereferenced() ? &this_type::m_ptr : NULL;
    }

private:
    lazy_ptr<T, F> * m_ptr;         // shared *lazy* pointer to the actual object
    ReferenceCount m_references;    // shared reference count to our lazy pointer
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the deferred allocation of backing for the addresses is the goal, rather than necessarily specifically committing on first use? If so, it looks as if Windows will do that for you automatically!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366803(v=vs.85).aspx

Relevant-looking quotation:

> As an alternative to dynamic
>   allocation, the process can simply
>   commit the entire region instead of
>   only reserving it. Both methods result
>   in the same physical memory usage
>   because committed pages do not consume
>   any physical storage until they are
>   first accessed.

As for new pages being reset to zero, I believe this is a security feature and can't be avoided. (The system has a special thread that zeros pages when there is some dead time, so with any luck there will always be a zeroed page immediately ready for use when necessary.)

Comment: The problem here is that it will only let me make allocations for which there is enough free virtual memory.  I'd like to make gigantic allocations (magnitudes larger than RAM + swap).  Clearly this will have to fail at some point in the future if I touch too many pages, but I don't mind about that.

Comment: The docs suggest that VirtualAlloc will do exactly what you want, I think? The page file will grow as required, disk space permitting, so that's no hard limit. As for free virtual memory, you are bound by that whatever you do, though, because that's the limit on the address space. (You can add a few more bits in 32-bit mode using PAE - Windows supports this but I've never used it.)

Comment: I don't want to be limited by disk space (ie ram + swap)..  I want to make truly gigantic allocations on 64-bit, and only have the pages committed and swap space increased as I touch them.

Comment: "Committed pages do not consume any physical storage until they are first accessed" strongly suggests to me that VirtualAlloc is the right place to start looking, even if should ultimately turn out that Windows won't do what you want.

Comment: I'll try this out then, but my understanding is that the pages will be accounted for if not yet allocated to regions of RAM or swap. I expect this accounting to fail, but I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I got round to trying this on Vista-64, unfortunately it fails to commit.  I can successfully reserve 1Tb of memory (I have less than 1Tb of free disk space), but I cannot commit 1Tb.  Looking at the page you link to again, it says: "For very large allocations, pre-committing an entire allocation can cause the system to run out of committable pages, resulting in virtual memory allocation failures."